# C# - Calculate total price on datagridview

Tags: c#

I created a method which detects when a Product with the same barcode is entered and instead of entering it as a new row it only increments it's quantity. The problem is that i have a fourth row in which the total price should be displayed but it is not.

CODE:

```
private void AddProduct()
    {
        bool Found = false;

        if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)


                if (Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value) == txtBarcode.Text)
                {
                    row.Cells[3].Value =Convert.ToString(1 + Convert.ToInt64(row.Cells[3].Value));
                    Found = true;
                    //break;
                }

        }
        if (!Found)

        {

            price = float.Parse(txtPrice.Text);
            Quantity = float.Parse(Quantity.Text);
            FinalPrice = price * Quantity;

            var firstRow = txtBarcode.Text;
            var secRow = txtName.Text;
            var thirdRow = price;
            var fourthrow = quantity;
            var fifthrow = FinalPrice;


            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(firstRow, secRow, thirdRow , fourthrow, fifthrow );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you debug your code?

Comment: It is not showing any errors , but it is not updating the fifth row with the final price

Comment: What returns in `Finle price`? Have you check?

Comment: then do `row.Cells[4].Value =Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt64(row.Cells[2].Value) * Convert.ToInt64(row.Cells[4].Value));` before you break. you are obviously only updating the quantity in your code before you set `Found = true;` and want to break

Comment: fourth row showing Quantity, change it with final Price.It may also solve.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here, because your code isn't the cleanest, but you seem to be updating only the quantity in your grid. Try this (also somewhat cleaner)

```
var existingRow = dataGridView1.Rows
    .Where(r => Convert.ToString(r.Cells[0].Value) == txtBarcode.Text)
    .SingleOrDefault();

if(existingRow != null)
{
    var price = Convert.ToInt64(existingRow.Cells[2].Value);
    var quantity = Convert.ToInt64(existingRow.Cells[3].Value);

    existingRow.Cells[3].Value = quantity + 1;
    existingRow.Cells[4].Value = price * (quantity + 1);
}
else
{
    // Your !found logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling calculations method after barcode is found.
Like.

```
                   if (Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value) == 
                     txtBarcode.Text)
                         {
                          row.Cells[3].Value =Convert.ToString(1 + 
                           Convert.ToInt64(row.Cells[3].Value;

               price = float.Parse(txtPrice.Text);
               Quantity = float.Parse(Quantity.Text);
               FinalPrice = price * Quantity;

                       Found = true;
                //break;
                      }
```